# Generating PDF handouts with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have several PPT files with slides, that I want to convert to a single PDF with slide per page + lines for notes. I then want to print that PDF and give it as handouts. What is the best and easiest way to do that?

Slides are 16:9, and I can convert them to PDF directly from PowerPoint. The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to "print" them into PDF with the lines for notes (and page-numbers).

Hopefully it's easy to do with ghostscript?

Comment: I don't know about using ghostscript directly, but I've done similar things using a python script and the [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) module (e.g. putting four slides from a PDF on a single page)